# How to set current date to jDateChooser from pc?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8

I have a situation that I need to fill the `jDateChooser` box by the current date automatically (without clicking the pop up calender).

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This one](http://www.se.rit.edu/~sal/uitutorials/uitot/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser.html#setDate(java.util.Date))?

Comment: I found my answer. Sorry if i bother anyone guys!

Comment: I found this one easier --
first i need to pick up the current date 

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = new Date();
then just set it to the jdatechooser field 
        jDateChooser.setDate(date);

Comment: Why do you need the format?

Comment: aah, actually I am working with mysql. There I need date in this format yyyy-MM-dd to save it or edit the existing data. that's why I formatted it but for simple use you don't need to format date. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pick up the current date *with desired format (format is necessary when you work with database)* -

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
Date date = new Date();
```

Then just set it to the `jdatechooser` field

`jDateChooser.setDate(date);`

Answer (score 4):

```
Date date = new Date();
dateChooser.setDate(date);
```

Comment: While this post may answer the question, it is still a good idea to add some explanation and, possibly, some links to the relevant documentation. Answers with good explanations and references are usually more useful both to the current OP and to the future visitors. Full detailed answers are also more likely to attract positive votes.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the Date class belongs to the java.util package. So, either import java.util.Date or use:

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
dateChooser.setDate(date);
```